# How would you calculate this partial derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, partial-derivative

Given the function $z^{2}x-yz+2xy=4$ how would you find $z_{x}$? I've tried doing it by rearranging to obtain a function in the form $z=f(x,y)$, but this doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: perhaps try using the quadratic formula to find an expression for $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ and then differentiate.

Comment: Partially differentiate the whole expression with respect to x (needs the product rule at some point). Note that $y_x$ is 0 as x and y are assumed independent. Re-arrange what you have to get $z_x$ in terms of z, y and x.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @John, the quadratic equation in terms of z will be

```
xz^2 - yz + (2xy - 4) = 0
```

Now, z can be written as (formula for roots of quadratic equation):

```
z = (y +/- (y^2 - 4x(2xy - 4))^(1/2))/(2x)
```

Simplifying further,

```
z = (y +/- (y^2 - 8yx^2 + 16x))^(1/2))/(2x)
```

Now, dz/dx can be found by differentiating this expression w.r.t. x

I get following result:

```
dz/dx = -y/(2x^2) +/- (1-xy)/(x(y^2-8yx^2+16x)^3/2) -/+ ((y^2-8yx^2+16x)^1/2)/(2x^2)
```